# Difference between Hinduism and Buddhist Tara maa

Tags: buddhism, tara

A Shakti worshipper worships the 2nd mahavidya , Tara maa , which resembles the one present in Tara pith temple . This is a Hindu perception, but in Buddhism also there is mention and strong practice of Tara worship. Could anyone clarify whether both the Tara maa’s are the same or are they different? Thank you.

Comment: See Sadhanamala for the Buddhist Tara & Brihattantrasara of Krishnananda Agamavagisha for the Hindu Tara.

Comment: In Hinduism, Tara is a manifestation of Adyashakti, while in Buddhism, Tara is a female bodhisattva. In Hinduism, the ultimate aim of Tara sadhana is to attain Mukti as described in Vedanta & Shakta Tantras, while in Buddhism, Tara sadhana is aimed to propel the aspirant in achieving the state of complete voidness as espoused by Shunyavadis like Nagarjuna, Bhaviveka, Dharmakirti, Shantarakshita & other heresiarchs. Tara sadhana in Hinduism is based on accepting the existence of a Supreme Being & the individual soul, which is denied in Buddhist sadhana.